# Bluemix SSO only recognizing one provider

Tags: single-sign-on, ibm-cloud

I have tested and used Bluemix SSO with a Liberty runtime on Bluemix successfully with the G+ login provider. Now I added LinkedIn and Cloud Directory providers as well.

However, when I try to login, it still always redirects me to the G+ login. When I disable G+ in the SSO service, it tells me "FBTIAS030E No login methods are configured.", even though the other two are enabled in the SSO config (and verified in case of LinkedIn).

I have restarted the runtime, and even re-staged it, to no avail.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Did you customize the login.html page? If you did, you can get the default template back by using the reset button at the Custom Design page. The default template displays the list of Identity Providers that you set up.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late reply, but I found the problem. The nice big switches in front of each provider (in the dashboard for the SSO service) were doing nothing in terms of switching providers on or off. You need to go to the "integrate" tab where the real switches are to enable the other providers.